# Execution Time exceed Quartz Scheduler Trigger every minute

Tags: java, execution

I have questions on how to use the scheduler properly.

I'm running a scheduler that trigger a job that sends list of emails at 10:00 am on working days.

The scheduler will trigger the job every 1 minute. However, the execution time for sending an email will take around 5 seconds.

Therefore, if I have 20 emails to send out for a day, it will take 20x5sec = 100 sec.

The scheduler will  trigger after 1 minute, before the 20 emails being sent out completely.

Therefore, some emails will be left unsent.

Please kindly advise me on how do I send out the email completely before the next trigger time ?

Below is my sample code.

```
//CalendarReminder.java

// Job 1 & Group 1
JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
job.setName("Job1");
job.setJobClass(SendEmailJob.class);       
job.setGroup("group1"); 

//example of adding an excluded day of the week - This excludes sundays from job     
//firing schedule       
WeeklyCalendar weeklyOff = new WeeklyCalendar();
weeklyOff.setDayExcluded(Calendar.SUNDAY, true);


// Trigger 1
//configure the scheduler time
SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);                
trigger.setRepeatInterval(60000); // Trigger every 1 min
trigger.setGroup("group1");
trigger.setName("trigger1");

try{           
//schedule the job
scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.addCalendar("weeklyOff", weeklyOff, false, true);
scheduler.start();           
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

}catch(Exception ex){


}


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SendEmailJob.java

try {                                              
//getting database connection to MySQL server
dbCon = DriverManager. getConnection(dbURL, username, password);

//getting PreparedStatment to execute query
stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);                               

//Resultset returned by query
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);   


while(rs.next()){

Str_Company = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.company");
Str_Dept = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.dept");
Str_EventType = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.eventtype");
Str_OneTimeDate = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.onetimedate");
Str_TimeSend = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.timesend");

Str_EmailFrom = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.emailfrom");                 
Str_EmailTo = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.emailto");                 
Str_EmailCCTo = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.emailccto");                 
Str_EmailSubject = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.emailsubject");                 
Str_EmailMessage = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.emailmessage");                 
Str_DeliveryStatus = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.deliverystatus");                 
Str_ActiveStatus = rs.getString("erscheduledemail.activestatus");                 

// Retrieve Scheduled Records Date yyyy-mm-dd & Time  hh:mm:ss
Int_Year = Integer.parseInt(Str_OneTimeDate.substring(0, 4));                   
Int_Month = Integer.parseInt(Str_OneTimeDate.substring(5, 7));                   
Int_Day = Integer.parseInt(Str_OneTimeDate.substring(8,10));                          
Int_Hour = Integer.parseInt(Str_TimeSend.substring(0, 2));                   
Int_Min = Integer.parseInt(Str_TimeSend.substring(3, 5));
Int_Sec = Integer.parseInt(Str_TimeSend.substring(6, 8));

// Retrieve Computer System Date & Time
Calendar SysCalen = Calendar.getInstance();
int sys_calYear =  SysCalen.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int sys_calMonth = SysCalen.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int sys_calDay = SysCalen.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int sys_calHour = SysCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int sys_calMinute = SysCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int sys_calSecond = SysCalen.get(Calendar.SECOND);

// If the time match at 10:00 am
if(sys_calYear == Int_Year && sys_calMonth == Int_Month && sys_calDay == Int_Day &&
sys_calHour == Int_Hour && sys_calMinute == Int_Min /*&& sys_calSecond == Int_Sec*/){



System.out.println( " The time now" + String.valueOf(sys_calHour) + ":" + 
String.valueOf(sys_calMinute) + ":" + String.valueOf(sys_calSecond)); 
System.out.println( " company: " +Str_Company); 


SendingEmail(Str_EmailFrom,Str_EmailTo,Str_EmailCCTo, Str_EmailSubject, Str_
EmailMessage);



// Update deliverystatus to Yes and ActiveStatus to No
stm = dbCon.createStatement();

sql = "UPDATE erscheduledemail SET deliverystatus = 'Y', activestatus = 'N' " 
+                       
"WHERE company = '"+Str_Company+"' and dept = '"+Str_Dept+"'  and onetimedate = 
'"+Str_OneTimeDate+"' and eventtype = '"+Str_EventType+"' ";



//Execute INSERT SQL Statement

stm.executeUpdate(sql)                                    ;
}
}

dbCon.close();                              

} catch (SQLException ex) {
//System.out.println("SQL Exception thrown :" + ex);               

System.out.println("SQL Exception thrown :" + ex);

}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Goshen

Comment: Why do you run your job every minute and not every day at 10?

Comment: thanks i have resolved the problem by running job every hour.